# Explicitly set JSESSIONID

Tags: java, session-variables, jsessionid

So, I'm in the middle of building an application where I want the user to be able to send a link to another user and work on the same data. There is little need to persist the data for more than 15 minutes and I want the application to not have to rely on a database.

I have a few variables which I am currently storing in a HttpSession.

Ideally I'd like to be able to set a parameter "sid" in the URL, and use that to set the session ID on the second client's browser - the one that's received a link with the SID.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to change the SID of a current session once it's been set up.

The only solution I've come up with so far is referring to the doGet() with a `HttpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+ getSessionId())` method, and getting the data with a specific session that way, but this seems pretty clunky.

Any suggestions?

### EDIT

This has seemingly turned into a discussion about the wisdom of setting two users up to have the same session so session vars may be kept the same. Note that a non-db, ie *light weight* solution was what I was looking for. PHP allows you to arbitrarily set a session ID to do this, but I'm deploying to Tomcat in this instance. Something which allows lightweight sharing of a few parameters, that's it...

What I've done, then, is to set context vars using `context.setAttribute()`. Ugly as sin, but all I can come up with, unless anyone has any better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach has some security issues because you are simulating [session hijacking] with it [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking):

> In computer science, session hijacking, sometimes also known as cookie
>   hijacking is the exploitation of a valid computer session—sometimes
>   also called a session key—to gain unauthorized access to information
>   or services in a computer system. In particular, it is used to refer
>   to the theft of a magic cookie used to authenticate a user to a remote
>   server. It has particular relevance to web developers, as the HTTP
>   cookies used to maintain a session on many web sites can be easily
>   stolen by an attacker using an intermediary computer or with access to
>   the saved cookies on the victim's computer (see HTTP cookie theft).

Better approach is to set your data in a way that both users can approach it from their sessions. If you are using single server you can do that with some global data within a server. In clustered or cloud environments you'll need some common storage for that (ie. database, global cache, etc.)

### EDIT

You are on a right track to share data among two users with different sessions.

> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine
>   where an attribute allows a servlet container to give the servlet
>   additional information.

Attributes are meant to be used to share data inside container among servlets of the same web application.

For clusters:

> In the case of a web application marked "distributed" in its
>   deployment descriptor, there will be one context instance for each
>   virtual machine. In this situation, the context cannot be used as a
>   location to share global information (because the information won't be
>   truly global). Use an external resource like a database instead.

Comment: That's true, but in this case the data is not being persisted and the network is set up such that it is not a concern.

Comment: Global cache would be a lot easier to implement, maintain, and extend than session sharing. If you do manage to find away to implement it via session, you may find that it's patched out in a newer version of Java.

Comment: In your case both users will share same session. So one user can change other users private data. Is this acceptable for you?

Comment: Still, it is a strange approach to hand over a user's session to another user as part of normal workflow. Use the application scope to share data across users.

Comment: @user987339 Yes, sharing the same data would be fine.
Ralf, You mean to set the vars in the ServletContext?

Comment: So, for instance, I can change personal data of the other user (email, name, etc)?

Comment: I've answered your question twice already. If it was an application that dealt with that sort of data, then yes. But it's not. I'm afraid this "hijacking" thing you've raised has rather taken over the entire question and is not really relevant to the question. Setting a custom session ID is trivial in PHP, I was merely trying to see if there was a way of doing the same in JEE.

Comment: If you are on EE6 then you can annotate the scope of CID beans. Have a look at this chapter of the [EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html).